# ejabberd domain/hostname name

Tags: ubuntu, dns, xmpp, ejabberd

I am trying to create my own ejabberd server that will be used as part of a messaging app

I am having some trouble understanding how the configuration works.

Let me explain where I am:

I started by buying a domain from Godaddy - lets calls it chat.com

I developed a website to explain the app etc and hosted it using Hostgator - they provided me with a shared IP address and name servers which I have assigned to my domain.

So the website works.

To create an xmpp sever, I have purchased a cloud sever with Rackspace and I am using an Ubuntu instance. Rackspace have provided me with an public IP and I can connect to the server remotely via SSH.

My next task is to install and configure an ejabberd server. Within the configuration of ejabberd we are asked to define a host name

```
{hosts, ["localhost"]}.
```

From what I have read you can change this to your domain. So I want users to have accounts in the format of user@chat.com and to be able to use this to log through my client via the web.

I do not think replacing local host with chat.com will work and I am failing to figure out how it authenticates that I have permission to use this domain.

Another point I would like to add is that this will be a closed network where users can only add and talk to other users with a @chat.com domain.

Can anyone please provide some clarity. I apologies if the answer is stupidly obvious.

Thanks, 
Saj

Answer (score 0):

So, your clients need to hit the cloud host after they resolve chat.com dns. Obviously it will return your website host. The simplest solution, which avoids dns magic, is to add some preffix for your clients - mobile.chat.com points - that will point clients to xmpp server. That should match the host config.

Answer (score -1):

It is the late response, but I write the correct way for setting up ejabberd here for others:
https://svn.process-one.net/ejabberd/tags/ejabberd-2.1.0/doc/guide.html#htoc22
As this guide tells, the workflow never go as they tell in above guide.

You need to go /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.cfg at first and register your domain.
next, you should register admin user.

Comment: URL is dead now.